# Appending to a list only appends first item

Tags: python, list, append

I have a list that im trying to inject data into. List one looks like this

```
data2 = ['TECH2_HELP', 'TECH2_1507', 'TECH2_1189', 'TECH2_4081', 'TECH2_5625', 'TECH2_4598', 'TECH2_1966', 'TECH2_2573', 'TECH2_1800', 'TECH2_1529']
```

The master list I am trying to make will be printed like this with my existing config. This below print is not the anticipated outcome, as you can see its only adding the first item in the data2 list. Secondly when i try a for loop I get all the data2 data mashed together in the same list see data3.

```
config1 = ['interface Gi3/0/13', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/7', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP', '!', 'interface Gi1/0/11', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/35', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/41', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/25', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/43', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/23', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/19', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/39', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP', '!']
```

```
data3=['interface Gi3/0/13', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP','description TECH2_1507','description TECH2_1189','description TECH2_4081','description TECH2_5625','description TECH2_4598','description TECH2_1966','description TECH2_2573','description TECH2_1800','description TECH2_1529', '!','interface Gi3/0/7', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP','description TECH2_1507','description TECH2_1189','description TECH2_4081','description TECH2_5625','description TECH2_4598','description TECH2_1966','description TECH2_2573','description TECH2_1800','description TECH2_1529', '!','interface Gi1/0/11', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP','description TECH2_1507','description TECH2_1189','description TECH2_4081','description TECH2_5625','description TECH2_4598','description TECH2_1966','description TECH2_2573','description TECH2_1800','description TECH2_1529', '!','interface Gi3/0/35', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP','description TECH2_1507','description TECH2_1189','description TECH2_4081','description TECH2_5625','description TECH2_4598','description TECH2_1966','description TECH2_2573','description TECH2_1800','description TECH2_1529', '!','interface Gi3/0/41', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP','description TECH2_1507','description TECH2_1189','description TECH2_4081','description TECH2_5625','description TECH2_4598','description TECH2_1966','description TECH2_2573','description TECH2_1800','description TECH2_1529', '!','interface Gi3/0/25', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP','description TECH2_1507','description TECH2_1189','description TECH2_4081','description TECH2_5625','description TECH2_4598','description TECH2_1966','description TECH2_2573','description TECH2_1800','description TECH2_1529', '!',['interface Gi3/0/43', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP','description TECH2_1507','description TECH2_1189','description TECH2_4081','description TECH2_5625','description TECH2_4598','description TECH2_1966','description TECH2_2573','description TECH2_1800','description TECH2_1529', '!','interface Gi3/0/23', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP','description TECH2_1507','description TECH2_1189','description TECH2_4081','description TECH2_5625','description TECH2_4598','description TECH2_1966','description TECH2_2573','description TECH2_1800','description TECH2_1529', '!','interface Gi3/0/19', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP','description TECH2_1507','description TECH2_1189','description TECH2_4081','description TECH2_5625','description TECH2_4598','description TECH2_1966','description TECH2_2573','description TECH2_1800','description TECH2_1529', '!','interface Gi3/0/39', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP','description TECH2_1507','description TECH2_1189','description TECH2_4081','description TECH2_5625','description TECH2_4598','description TECH2_1966','description TECH2_2573','description TECH2_1800','description TECH2_1529', '!',
```

Ive tried dividing this up doing a for and len on data2 but when i do that it places all the data in that list in a row.

```py
            for line1 in data1:
                words1 = line1.split()
                if len(words1) > 0:
                    local = ''.join(words1[0:1])
                    config1.append('interface ' + local)
                    config1.append('power inline static max 30000')
                    config1.append('spanning-tree portfast')
                    description = ''.join(data2[:1])
                    config1.append('description ' + description)
                    config1.append('!')  # totally optional
                    hostname = None
```

**the expected list value should look like the below.**

```
expected_config1 = ['interface Gi3/0/13', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/7', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_1507', '!', 'interface Gi1/0/11', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_1189', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/35', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_4081', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/41', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_5625', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/25', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_4598', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/43', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_1966', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/23', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_2573', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/19', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_1800', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/39', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_1529', '!']
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't quite understand what is your end goal - can you clarify? Just provide the input lists since you already provided the output one.

Comment: The end goal is to merge the description into the config1 list. Input list in question is data2.

Comment: data1 list in the code is the interface list i.e. 'interface Gi3/0/13'. That list is appending properly, as you can see from the above config1 output.

Comment: I think I solved your problem, but i need a bit more info because that may change the otherwise simple solution: is data2 a list of strings like in your question? If yes, there is no need to join its elements like here `description = ''.join(data2[:1])`.

Comment: Data2 type is a list of strings. However I get a compile issue that I can't iterate a str if I don't join. Thanks for your help @atru

Comment: Gladly, let me know if you have any more questions. Btw., I've learned the hard way that it's best not to call major variables `config1`, `data1` etc. It's a personal choice but when you get back to the code after a while it's much easier to navigate it when variables have some more meaningful names.

Comment: Yea I'm starting to learn that, confused myself so many times during this process with my crappy names. Thanks for your help @atru appreciate the words of wisdom as well.

Comment: You're welcome :) like said, learned it myself the hard way :D I remember one of my first programs where not only the names were off but one of the main parameters was set at like line 201 ... yesss... the code got a good refactoring later along with proper splitting into functions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the handling of `data2`, otherwise your overall appending strategy was correct.

First, you were always fetching only the first element of `data2`. One solution for this is to maintain a separate counter (here `kdt`) that will increase every time you execute the appending phase thus keeping track of which `data2` element to append,

```
data2 = ['TECH2_HELP', 'TECH2_1507', 'TECH2_1189', 'TECH2_4081', 'TECH2_5625', 'TECH2_4598', 'TECH2_1966', 'TECH2_2573', 'TECH2_1800', 'TECH2_1529']

config1 = []
data1 = ['Gi3/0/13 some more text']*len(data2)

kdt = 0
for line1 in data1:
    words1 = line1.split()
    if len(words1) > 0:
        local = ''.join(words1[0:1])
        config1.append('interface ' + local)
        config1.append('power inline static max 30000')
        config1.append('spanning-tree portfast')
        description = data2[kdt]
        config1.append('description ' + description)
        config1.append('!')  # totally optional
        hostname = None
        kdt += 1

print config1
```

This prints:

```
['interface Gi3/0/13', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_HELP', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/13', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_1507', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/13', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_1189', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/13', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_4081', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/13', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_5625', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/13', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_4598', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/13', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_1966', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/13', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_2573', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/13', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_1800', '!', 'interface Gi3/0/13', 'power inline static max 30000', 'spanning-tree portfast', 'description TECH2_1529', '!']
```

Second issue was that by using `data2[0:1]` you were actually creating a list with one string, the first element of `data2`. Without joining, this would cause an attempt to concatenate a string and a list with `+` in this line,

```
config1.append('description ' + description)
```

which I assume was the error you were seeing. By accessing the correct elements by their index, you're actually retrieving a string, so the joining operation is not needed.